# Perl: Filter AoH output

Tags: arrays, perl, hash, output

I'm trying to sort my AoH which looks like this:

```
$VAR1 = [
              {
                'Name' => 'John',
                'Lastname' => 'Derp',
                'Organization' => 'Finance',
                'OfficeNR' => '23',
                'ID' => '145'
              },
              {
                'Name' => 'Kate',
                'Lastname' => 'Herp',
                'Organization' => 'HR',
                'OfficeNR' => '78',
                'ID' => '35'
              },
              {
                'Name' => 'Jack',
                'Lastname' => 'Serp',
                'Organization' => 'Finance',
                'OfficeNR' => '23',
                'ID' => '98'
              }
       ];
```

What I'm trying to do is to filter my output using keys from AoH, for example print out only those who have `'Organization' => 'Finance'`.

I've tried to solve it using new array:

```
my @SortedAoH = sort { {Organization=>{'Finance'}} } @AoH;
```

But it doesn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you want is `grep`, not `sort`. You are getting the basic syntax of equivalence checking wrong as well.

Anyway, the filter is:

```
my @finance_orgs = grep { $_->{'Organization'} eq 'Finance' } @AoH;
```

The `@finance_orgs` variable will now only include the ones with `Organization` set to `Finance`.

Just an explanation of the pieces:

- The `$_` variable is the variable that gets assigned whenever the value is implied in a block, such as in `grep` or `map` or in a `for` loop without an explicitly named variable.
- `$_->{'Organization'}` performs a hash lookup on the hash as it iterates through each entry in your array.
- `eq` is the operator used to test for string equivalence (as opposed to `==` which tests for numeric equivalence).